# dsniff is unable to read wireshark pcap file

Tags: wireshark, pcap

To try DSNIFF with -p (getting passwords with pcap) option

First i've captured packets of my Open access point with airodump-ng and saved them to a pcap file and dsniff worked easily with no error *But now* i am trying to capture with wireshark and dsniff is giving an error and not working..

```
dsniff -p file.pcap
```

Dsniff's output is just:

```
dsniff: using file.pcap
```

i have tried every format in wireshark but dsniff in unable to read it.. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

dSniff was not upgraded since few years. I believe your problem is caused by the fact that files saved by Wireshark are in fact pcap-ng (next gen) which is different than old pcap.

I would suggest two solutions:

1. convert pcap-ng file to pcap using one of the available tools ([pcapng.com](http://pcapng.com/) or `editcap` tool that comes with wireshark).
2. compile dsniff from source with new `libpcap`.